# Can we add select dropdown of custom module in shopware 6 admin category module?

Tags: javascript, admin, shopware, administration, shopware6

I have created one module **Color**

I want to add this module to **shopware 6** default module which is **Category**

Is it possible to add dropdown list with multiple select of **Color** when we add/edit **Category**

I did try to do it with custom field option, but my color module has multiple fields which I can use in front side.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to your question and describe your specific challenge with that code.

Comment: I haven't tried any code, before moving to the development, I want to make sure this is possible somehow

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way to do this would indeed be using custom fields. As you already noted the custom field referring to an entity will only contain a single value, by default the id of the entity. You can use the id to resolve the referenced entity when the category is loaded.

Step 1: Create the custom field

```php
$customFieldSetRepository = $container->get('custom_field_set.repository');
$customFieldSetRepository->create([
    [
        'name' => 'my_custom_field_set_color',
        'label' => ['en-GB' => 'Color'],
        'relations' => [[
            'entityName' => 'category',
        ]],
        'customFields' => [
            [
                'name' => 'my_custom_field_color',
                'type' => 'select',
                'config' => [
                    'label' => ['en-GB' => 'Color'],
                    'entity' => 'color',
                    'labelProperty' => 'name',
                    'customFieldType' => 'entity',
                    'componentName' => 'sw-entity-single-select',
                    'customFieldPosition' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Step 2: Set up a subscriber to fetch the referenced entity from the id in the custom field when the category is loaded. To store your custom entity with the category entity you can use an extension.

```php
class CategorySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * in the service definition this would be the repository of your
     * custom entity, e.g. 'color.repository'
     */
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $repository;

    public function __construct(
        EntityRepositoryInterface $repository
    ) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'sales_channel.' . CategoryEvents::CATEGORY_LOADED_EVENT => 'entityLoaded',
        ];
    }

    public function entityLoaded(EntityLoadedEvent $event): void
    {
        /** @var CategoryEntity $category */
        foreach ($event->getEntities() as $category) {
            $customFields = $category->getCustomFields();

            if (empty($customFields['my_custom_field_color'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $criteria = new Criteria([$customFields['my_custom_field_color']]);
            $entity = $this->repository->search($criteria, $event->getContext())->first();

            if (!$entity) {
                continue;
            }

            $category->addExtension('myCustomFieldColor', $entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3: In the template you check for the extension and if it exists you can use the extension as an entry point to your custom entity.

```
{% if category.extensions.myCustomFieldColor is defined %}
    {{ category.extensions.myCustomFieldColor.hexCode }}
{% endif %}
```

---

Another way to this would be to use an [`EntityExtension`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities) to add a proper association from your custom entity to `category`. This will allow you to reference your entity when querying categories with the DAL, e.g. for filtering by color. From the point of performance this would also be preferable, but the implementation requires more steps. If you decide to go that route, I have an [example repository](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneCustomerHeightExtension) where I add an association from a custom entity to the `customer` entity and manually add a field for it in the administration. Maybe this will be of help.